# How to measure time of function using js proxy

Tags: javascript, function, es6-proxy

I would like to measure time of my all function in my class `Foo`.

My code is:

```
class Foo {
    constructor() {
        return new Proxy(this, {
            get(target, prop, receiver) {
                console.log(`Calling '${prop}'`); 
                return target[prop];
            },
        });
    }

    myFn() {
        console.log('hi');
    }
}

new Foo().myFn();
```

Problem is, that I need to return function from proxy. I tried to use code `return () => target[prop]();` but it looks like that `myFn` was not called.

Any tips? Maybe can I achieve it using `rxjs` lib?

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to return? In your code above, it seems to be working, however, the method `myFn()` doesn't return anything

Answer (score 0):

In your code above, if you are looking for `myFn()` to return a value, then you need to include a `return` statement in `myFn()`. You can see that `myFn()` did run as the console did log the `'hi'` message.

In the example snippet below, you can see that `anotherFn()` has a `return` statement, and thus the Proxy is returning what that method returned.

Keep in mind that if you use a static method, like the `staticFn()` in the snippet, the Class does not need to be instantiated with a `new`, and the constructor will not be triggered, not logging that method.

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    return new Proxy(this, {
      get(target, prop, receiver) {
        console.log(`Calling '${prop}'`);
        return target[prop];
      },
    });
  }
  myFn() {
    console.log('hi');
  }
  anotherFn(string) {
    return string
  }
  static staticFn(message) {
    return message
  }
}

console.log({
  myFn: new Foo().myFn(),
  anotherFn: new Foo().anotherFn('hello'),
  staticFn: Foo.staticFn('world')
})
```